# How to aggregate and calculate averages efficiently in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql, aggregate

I have Firestore set up with several collections. Notably, I have a grades collection, with a document for each question.

My goal is to aggregate these grades and calculate the average for each module. I understand that Firestore, being a NoSQL database, doesn't natively support server-side computations or complex aggregation queries.

So far, I've considered two approaches:

Reading all documents on the client side: I could fetch all relevant documents and calculate the average on the client side. However, this seems like it could become expensive as the number of documents grows.

Using Cloud Functions to calculate averages: This would involve triggering a Cloud Function to update an average whenever a new grade is added. However, this also seems like it could increase the number of write operations significantly.

Does anyone have any idea that wouldn't result in a crazy amount of reads or writes?

Comment: I just added an up-to-date answer -- hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

> Reading all documents on the client side: I could fetch all relevant documents and calculate the average on the client side. However, this seems like it could become expensive as the number of documents grows.

Reading all documents client-side isn't an option, as it can become costly when you reach a large number of documents in the collection. It might work only for small data sets.

> Using Cloud Functions to calculate averages: This would involve triggering a Cloud Function to update an average whenever a new grade is added.

That would be an option to calculate the average each time a new grade is added. This option should work hand in hand with the [count()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#use_the_count_aggregation) function. Also note, there are some [limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#limitations) when it comes to counting the documents in a collection or the document that are returned by a Firestore query. However, when it comes to [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#aggregation_queries), please note that:

> For aggregation queries such as `count()`, you are charged one document read for each batch of up to 1000 index entries matched by the query. For aggregation queries that match 0 index entries, there is a minimum charge of **one** document read.

So counting documents can be considered a really cheap operation.

> However, this also seems like it could increase the number of write operations significantly.

Since you write the new average each time a new grade is added, yes, the number of writes will increase, but on the other hand, you'll significantly decrease the number of reads, which will make it cheaper overall.

Comment: So you're saying the best option would be the firebase function? Ie:

-Have a document dedicated to holding the average value
-everytime a grade changes, a function is triggered, and that function gets the average by comparing it to a count() of all questions

Am i understanding that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, Ruder.

Comment: Hey Ruder. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Answer (score 0):

### November 2023 update

On Nov 8 2023 [Firebase announced](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/aggregate-with-sum-and-avg-in-firestore) the `AVG()` and `SUM()` aggregation functions ([check the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/aggregation-queries#web-modular-api_4)).

Since you've mentioned wanting to do this on the server side, you can now do the following in Node.js:

```
const gradesCollection = firestore.collection('grades');
const snapshot = await gameResultsCollection.aggregate({
  averageGrade: AggregateField.average('grade'),
}).get();

const { averageGrade } = snapshot.data();
```

Comment: I'm having AggregateField not found error.

Comment: @EktaPadaliya try updating to the latest version. Seems like there was an issue with `firebase-admin`.